# Replacing URL with text link in jquery flip wall

Tags: jquery, url

On Flip Wall (http://demo.tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/demo.php) on the reverse of the square (once you click it and it flips over), I'd like to replace the URL e.g. www.google.com with just the text "Google", and still have the text hyperlinked.

Any ideas how to do this? Original script is here:
http://tutorialzine.com/2010/03/sponsor-wall-flip-jquery-css/

Answer (score 0):

I've never used this, but from the link you gave us, the HTML should look like this :

```
<div class="sponsorFlip">
    <img alt="More about google" src="img/sponsors/google.png">
</div>

<div class="sponsorData">
    <div class="sponsorDescription">
        The company that redefined web search.
    </div>
    <div class="sponsorURL">
        <a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/ </a>
    </div>
</div>
```

I guess you can change this part:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">http://www.google.com/ </a>
```

To:

```
<a href="http://www.google.com/">Google</a>
```

Comment: Karl, the code is generated by a php loop, only allows a URL. <?php
   
   // Looping through the array:
   
   foreach($sponsors as $company)
   {
    echo'
    <div class="sponsor" title="Click to flip">
     <div class="sponsorFlip">
      <img src="img/icons/'.$company[0].'.png" alt="More about '.$company[0].'" />
     </div>
     
     <div class="sponsorData">
      <div class="sponsorDescription">
       '.$company[1].'
      </div>
      <div class="sponsorURL">
       <a href="'.$company[2].'">'.$company[2].'</a>
      </div>
     </div>
    </div>
    
    ';
   }
  
  ?>

Comment: You could try this put this inside the `<a>` : `ucfirst (preg_replace('/.\.(.)\../', '$1', $company[2]))`. Note that im not an expert of regexp and PHP, so it may be wrong.